# WARNING: [ServiceBusTechnology] features were found in myproject.jpr but are not installed. Install these technologies before you proceed

Tags: jdeveloper, osb

I inherited a project at work that uses Oracle Service Bus and was told to install JDeveloper. When I open the project, JDev says

> WARNING: [ServiceBusTechnology] features were found in myproject.jpr
> but are not installed. Install these technologies before you proceed.

What technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Bus is part of the SOA Suite. You have to download the [SOA Suite](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/soasuite/downloads.html) the normal JDev Studio installation doesn'T have the SOA stuff built in. However, how to proceed from there depends on the version you are using. You'll find the docs on the given page.